# Xamarin.Forms implement VideoView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to implement a VideoView into my Xamarin.Forms shared code class?

What I tried:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using XamNative.ViewModels;
using XamNative.Droid;


[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class VideoPage : ContentPage
{
    public VideoPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

#if __ANDROID__
    var linearLayout = new LinearLayout(Forms.Context);
    linearLayout.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

    var _videoView = new VideoView(linearLayout.Context) { };
    _videoView.SetMinimumHeight(300);
    _videoView.SetMinimumWidth(300);
    linearLayout.AddView(_videoView);

//MediaRecorder Code...
#endif
```

}

I think it has something to the with the VideoPage class inheriting from ContentPage, which is not the right inheritance.

The error is logged as "Application lost the surface".

I can implement a TextView this way, but not a VideoView

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Third Party Nuget as all the code is done for you.

You can either use:

**Rox.Xamarin.Video Player:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rox.Xamarin.Video/

Which is free.

Or a paid for component:

**Octane.VideoPlayer:** https://components.xamarin.com/view/video-player

Comment: No, this wont help, due to me wanting to record a video and give it a specific quality (480p / 720p...). These plugins dont support said usability.